# "Concatenate" PostgreSQL ints from select

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table Digits that contains INTs from 0 to 9.
What i want to do is to join in three or more times and make this values to be a value like 0,...,124,125,...998,999;

I'm doing something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Digits AS Fir JOIN
     Digits AS Sec
     ON TRUE JOIN
     Digits AS Thi
     ON TRUE;
```

But what i get is:
--+ --+---
     0 |     0 |     0
     0 |     0 |     1
     0 |     0 |     2
     0 |     0 |     3
     0 |     0 |     4
     0 |     0 |     5
     0 |     0 |     6
     0 |     0 |     7
     0 |     0 |     8
     0 |     0 |     9
     0 |     1 |     0
     0 |     1 |     1
     0 |     1 |     2
.
.
.
.
     9 |     9 |     9

Any ideas how can I convert it to get:
0
1
2
3
.
.
.
999

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES):

```
select val
from generate_series(0, 999) gs(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly multiply each digit by its position:

```
SELECT     100 * fir.digit + 10 * sec.digit + thi.digit
FROM       digits AS fir 
CROSS JOIN digits AS sec 
CROSS JOIN digits AS thi
```

(but in all fairness, [Gordon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50806715/2422776) is neater.)